# XAML: Property not found in type

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I am trying to build a custom Control with some additional properties:

```
public class EntryWithBorder : Entry
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsCurvedCornersEnabledProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            "IsCurvedCornersEnabled",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(EntryWithBorder),
            true);

    public bool IsCurvedCornersEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCurvedCornersEnabledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsCurvedCornersEnabledProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

Then I want to use the custom control from within a page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App.CustomControls;assembly=App"
             x:Class="App.View.LoginPage"
             BackgroundColor="{StaticResource BackgroundColor}">
    <ScrollView>
        <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="25">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="AUTO"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="0" HeightRequest="50"/>

            <!--header spacing-->
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <Image Source="test.PNG" Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
           <!-- <Image Source="CurvedLimiter.png" VerticalOptions="End" HeightRequest="50" Aspect="Fill"/>-->

            <!--header-->
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="2" HeightRequest="100"/>
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
                <local:EntryWithBorder IsCurvedCornersEnabled="True"  Placeholder="Email" Text="super@super.de" x:Name="emailEntry" Style="{StaticResource LoginEntry}"/>
                <Entry IsPassword="True" Placeholder="Password" Text="super" x:Name="passwordEntry" Style="{StaticResource LoginEntry}"/>
                <Switch x:Name="autoLogin" IsToggled="True" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                <Button Text="Login" x:Name="btnLogin" Clicked="btnLogin_Clicked" Style="{StaticResource LoginButton}"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <!--login-->
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="3"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

The custom control "local:EntryWithBorder" is found, however it cant find the bindableproperty "IsCurvedCornersEnabled". Instead I get an error XLS0413 the property could not be found within type "EntryWithBorder".

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 2018-09-16:** This problem could be solved by restarting VS. However I have to restart VS for every new BindableProperty that I add to the code.

So also, I got a new bug: As soon as I add the following Property to the code, I get an exception when the App Forms get initialized:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty Corner123RadiussProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(Corner123Radiuss),
        typeof(double),
        typeof(EntryWithBorder),
        7);

// Gets or sets CornerRadius value
public double Corner123Radiuss
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(Corner123RadiussProperty); }
    set { SetValue(Corner123RadiussProperty, value); }
}
```

The strange thing is that I dont even reference this property from my XAML code at this point. The Exception is thrown in the LoginPage within the InitializeComponents() method:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'App.CustomControls.EntryWithBorder' threw an exception.
```

I don't get any more information at this point.

I wrapped the project in a file here: [VS Project](https://expirebox.com/download/b2eada93e711817dec52af3c4a01e1a2.html)

Comment: looks fine to me looking at that code, provide a sample project so we can run and see what is actually causing this issue?

Comment: Seems to be a VS problem. After quitting and restarting VS the properties can be used from within XAML. However I have to restart VS for every new BindableProperty that I create... 
Also I got a new problem. I will update the post above.

Comment: Updated the post with a downloadable project. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
public static readonly BindableProperty Corner123RadiussProperty =
BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(Corner123Radiuss),
    typeof(double),
    typeof(EntryWithBorder),
    7);
```

To

```
public static readonly BindableProperty Corner123RadiussProperty =
BindableProperty.Create(
    nameof(Corner123Radiuss),
    typeof(double),
    typeof(EntryWithBorder),
    7.0);
```

This bindable property is `double` type, setting default value with `7` is handled as integer so it needs to be `7.0`

Comment: ... So obvious. Thank you very much!